# removing the file name from file path in linux

Tags: shell, unix, hdfs

My problem statement is I am having the whole hdfs path that may or may not have part* at the end on this.

Like: 
 **/user/root/daily_file/part*** or  **/user/root/daily_file/p***

I will have the above string in one variable in my shell script.

But I want to remove the last **part*** or **p*** what ever we have in between **"/" and "*".**

My code snippet is:

```
hdfs_path="/user/root/daily_file/part*"
hdfs dfs -test -e $hdfs_path
    rc=$?
    if [ "$rc" -eq "0" ]
    then
    echo -e  "path exist !!! \n"
    if
```

Due to path -

Comment: What is the purpose of this program? I mean, what do you want to do next? Perhaps what you seek is already there in the HDFS API (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html). I am not sure that I understood what the problem is...
Also check that the code snippet is complete. It ends with an `if`...

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
var="/user/root/daily_file/part*"
echo "${var%/*}"
```

If you want to get exactly `/user/root/daily_file/`, then: `newvar="${var%/*}/"`